# Change navigation menu font but not links below it

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, genesis

Is there a way to change the font in my main navigation menu without changing the fonts on the drop downs under them? I'm using Wordpress with a Genesis child theme. [This is my site](http://gleefulthings.com/WPtestblog/). I just want to change the font on the gray navigation bar, not the links under them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make CSS rules to this class

```
.genesis-nav-menu>li>a {
    //some CSS
}
```

Comment: This also affects the drop down menus unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

Just use the direct child selector example `header > ul {font-family:Arial}` this will select only the direct children of the header element but not anything deeper

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this works :( I'm using a plugin called Use Any Font to change it and I have to tell it which class.

Answer (score 0):

In your style.css on line 948 you have this block of style:

```
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Change it to have the font-family declaration in it e.g. if you have Verdana font to add for menu links:

```
    .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item {
       text-align: left;
       font-family: Verdana;
       }
```

It will change font for all menu links in Genesis theme, but will not effect any other links in the theme.

Comment: That does change the fonts in the drop down menu though because they are also part of the menu :( That's what I'm trying not to do.